# CreateRemoteThread says file doesn't exist, but it DOES exist

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll-injection, createremotethread

I am trying to inject a .dll into another process's memory, by using Interop.

This is my C# code:

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = Inject(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0].Id);

            Console.WriteLine(result);

            if (result < 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [DllImport("Testing.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Inject(int dwProcessId);
}
```

The code for the function `Inject` is this (notice the comment on `return -6`):

```
//C++ .dll that does actually exists
const char* DLL_NAME = "C:\\Users\\Bruno\\Source\\Repos\\CourseGuidance\\InteropTesting\Debug\\Loader.dll";

TESTING_API DWORD Inject(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessId);

    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return -1;

    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll");

    if (hModule == NULL)
        return -2;

    FARPROC pLoadLibrary = GetProcAddress(hModule, "LoadLibraryA");

    if (pLoadLibrary == NULL)
        return -3;

    LPVOID pMemory = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(DLL_NAME) + 1, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (pMemory == NULL)
        return -4;

    BOOL result = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pMemory, DLL_NAME, strlen(DLL_NAME) + 1, NULL);

    if (!result)
        return -5;

    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) pLoadLibrary, pMemory, 0, NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
        return -6;

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pMemory, strlen(DLL_NAME) + 1, MEM_RELEASE);

    CloseHandle(hThread);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

I think the error I am getting might be misleading, since the file does exist in that folder. I also thought the error could be because of `LoadLibraryA`, which is for ASCII, even tried using `LoadLibraryW`, but I still got the same issue.

If someone has an idea of what could be wrong, could you provide me the right direction?

Comment: What is the actual error? The hex error code? Could it be a dependency problem, the DLL depends on some other module that it can't find?

Comment: The actual code is `2`

Comment: You have a standard off-by-one bug, so common with C strings.  You are forgetting to copy the 0 terminator.  Use `strlen(DLL_NAME) + 1` instead.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems that is not the only problem, even though I changed all calls from `strlen(DLL_NAME)` to `strlen(DLL_NAME) + 1`, I still get the result.

Comment: In your const char* DLL_NAME, one of the backslashes has not been doubled.

Comment: Good eye, but even after adding the missing backslash the error keeps happening

Comment: Any reason why you aren't telling us what value the Inject function returned?

Comment: I just found out what the problem was. It was happening because my application is 32bit, while notepad is 64. There was probably mismanagement of memory space while allocating the memory for the dllname.

Answer (score 2):

You did not declare `Inject` as `SetLastError=true`. Therefore, the value you got from `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` is garbage:

> **[Marshal.GetLastWin32Error Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**
>
> Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function that
>   was called using platform invoke **that has the
>   DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set**.
>
> You can use this method to obtain error codes only if you apply the
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute to the method
>   signature and set the SetLastError field to true. The process for this
>   varies depending upon the source language used: **C# and C++ are false
>   by default**, but the Declare statement in Visual Basic is true.